# Subdivide mesh through heightmap curvature when using the displace modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

The displace modifier can be used to generate terrain from a heightmap. Is there a way to modify the mesh according to curvatures obtained from the heightmap?

Comment: Could You provide more detail?

Comment: I don't think this is possible atm (unless you count manually painting geometry with dyntopo), but hopefully will possible automatically be once [osd is fulled integrated](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/05/opensubdiv-gpu-tessellation-wip/)

Comment: @gandalf3 Note that I want to construct the mesh purely from the heightmap. An option "Subdivide mesh from texture" for the displace modifier would be nice. From that video, I would guess that osd will be used for something else.

Comment: @user877329 osd supports adaptive subdivision, which I think means it subdivides parts of a mesh which need it while keeping other parts low poly.

Comment: You could add a Decimate modifier after the Displace. This will reduce geometry on flat areas and leave more geometry at areas of high curvature.